# Doctrine: How to add custom order-by for all selects?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm looking for a way to add a custom orderBy statement for every entity in my application. The idea behind is ignoring articles like "the" and "a" when the query contains an "order by" for certain fields or an entity.

First thought was using listener, but there seems to be no preSelect, preQuery, etc. to hook into.

Any ideas, where to start or look at? Writing my own behavioral extension, perhaps? 
Thanks in advance.

PS: Context is a symfony2 2.(2/3) application.

Comment: May you provide some code to show how to use it?, maybe is something like $aQueryBuilder->addOrder('some_weird_stuff')?. I think that you should use a custom repository for this, but still not sure about what you need...